# Query for updating other table while inserting data into one table

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for solution to update and insert Table2 while inserting data into Table1,

Table1

```
---------------------------------------
| id |Student name | % | Date of Exam |
---------------------------------------
| 1  | Tom         | 80 | 12/03/2015  |
| 2  | Jack        | 90 | 12/03/2015  |
| 1  | Tom         | 85 | 21/05/2015  |
---------------------------------------
```

Table2 (to be updated)

```
---------------
| id  |  %    |
---------------
|  1  |  85   |
|  2  |  90   |
---------------
```

If the "id" is not present in the Table2 I want to insert, and if it exists, the table's row should be updated.

Please someone help me to find solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using? Also, kindly elaborate by providing the expected result.

Comment: Like a trigger you mean?

Comment: i am using sql server 2008. the expected result is i want to store "id" and "%" scored in last exam in Table2 from Table1 @wewesthemenace

Comment: You should also look into using indexed views, that might be a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a persisted table solution, you could use an `AFTER` trigger to recalculate the last result every time a row is inserted int `Table1` and insert / update `Table2` ("LastScore") accordingly, using the `inserted` pseudo rows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tCalcLastScore ON Table1
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
  DELETE a
  FROM LastScore a
  INNER JOIN inserted i
  on i.id = a.id;

  INSERT INTO LastScore(id, [Percent])
    SELECT id, [Percent] FROM
    ( SELECT t1.id, t1.[Percent], 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.DateOfExam DESC) AS RowId
      FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN inserted i 
           ON i.id = t1.id
    ) x WHERE RowId = 1;
END;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09233/1)

Notes

- Remember that the trigger must handle multiple `inserted` rows - I've used a `ROW_NUMBER` function with a filter to determine the last row for each student.
- If rows can be deleted from the first table, you'll also need to add a trigger to `ON DELETED` and handle the `deleted` pseudo rows as well
- I've been lazy and just deleted + reinserted into the second table (`LastScore`) but a merge is also possible.

However, a non-persisted alternative is to compute the last score each time on the fly using a view:

```
CREATE VIEW LastScore AS
   SELECT id, [Percent] 
   FROM
   (
     SELECT id, [Percent],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.DateOfExam DESC) AS RowId
          FROM Table1 t1
   ) x 
   WHERE RowId = 1;
```

[View Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c503e/1)

The performance of the view should be reasonable provided that there is an index on `Table1(id, DateOfExam)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trigger (on insert) or a stored procedure to insert or update one or more tables.

If table1 is ever updated, table2 should also be updated accordingly. Writing a Trigger on insert and update would be useful.